# Integration test with jersey and spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration test with jersey, Spring boot 1.4 and Spring data jpa.I am able to start embedded server but getting error from jersey side , any help will be appreciated.

Integration test

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;



@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes=Application.class)
public class ContactServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;

    @Test
    public void mergeContactsTest() {

        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/contacts/merge", String.class);
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("contacts merged");
    }

}
```

Contact Resource

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    @Path("/contacts")
    public class ContactResource {

        @Autowired
        private ContactService contactService;

        @GET
        @Path("merge")
        public Response mergeContacts() throws IOException {
            contactService.mergeContacts();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED) 
                    .entity("contacts merged").build();

        }

    }
```

Stack trace:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.configure(JacksonFeature.java:73) ~[jersey-media-json-jackson-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:680) ~[jersey-common-2.7.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:610) ~[jersey-common-2.7.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:800) ~[jersey-server-2.7.jar:na]

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all it looks like you're mixing jersey versions (2.23.1 / 2.7). Please share informations about your imports.

Comment: I have added imports, i am using spring-boot-starter-jersey

Comment: Spring Boot pulls in Jersey 2.23.1. Make sure that any Jersey dependencies you explicitly declare, use the same version

Comment: Earlier i had 2.7 version but now i am pointing to Spring boot dependency only.

Comment: Thanks to both of u for pointing me to jar conflict ..after removing other jar from repo...I am able to run it .Thanks